# Why scipy.distance.cdist has a big performance difference between using float32 (slower) and float64 (faster)?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

Why scipy.distance.cdist has a big performance difference between using float32 and float64?

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
import time

a_float32 = np.empty((1000000, 512), dtype=np.float32)
b_float32 = np.empty((1, 512), dtype=np.float32)
a_float64 = np.empty((1000000, 512), dtype=np.float64)
b_float64 = np.empty((1, 512), dtype=np.float64)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    distance.cdist(a_float32, b_float32, "sqeuclidean")
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    distance.cdist(a_float64, b_float64, 'sqeuclidean')
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

On my computer, this code produces a timing of 130.6998474597931 for float32 and 22.450339794158936 for float64, a whopping 6x difference. ***What is the reason for such a big difference with float64 being faster than float32?***

However the gap seems to become smaller and smaller if instead of b being np.empty((1, 512)), b is np.empty((k, 512)) with k (>1) becoming larger and larger. For example, when k=5, I get 222.25975680351257 for float32 and 110.36117148399353 for float64 (2x). ***Why the gap becomes smaller when k becomes larger?***

Comment: It's harder to vectorize operations with float64s.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry typo. float64 is faster than float32. See the edit.

Comment: It may be using some compiled code that preferentially works with the machine default floats.

Comment: No idea if this is the case here, but some tools only support the calculations with a type, and do the conversion to be compatible with the other type. So the float32 table may be converted to float64 first, calculation performed, then converted back to float32.

Comment: How about telling us your CPU and OS?

Comment: @MarkSetchell cpu is intel i7-7700k, os is linux

Answer (score 5):

The underlying C code that actually does the computation is implemented using C `double` variables, which are 64 bit floating point values.  When you pass in arrays of `np.float32`, the data must be copied.

For the second part of your question: larger `k` means more work, so the overhead of copying the data is a smaller fraction of the overall time.